# Unable to Display Help Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

When I press F1 for help in Access, I got the following message.

"You need an Internet connection to view Visual Basic Help, but your administrator doesn't allow you to connect"

I'm using Access 2013 running on a Win 7 machine.

How can I get my help back?

I used to be able to view help offline from my old Access 2003. Since I "upgraded" to 2013, I'm not able to see help any more.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you just get an internet connection?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin yes, I do have internect connection. that's why I can post in stackoverflow btw...

Comment: D'oh. Yes, of course, sorry.

Comment: BTW, this is the sort of thing that might get more coverage on SuperUser, a SO sister site?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when hitting the F1 key in Excel 2013 VBA after I had upgraded from Office 2003:

> "You need an Internet connection to view Visual Basic Help, but your administrator doesn't allow you to connect"

I also noticed that the "Sign In"  control was missing from the top right hand corner of the Excel 2013 ribbon (and from Word 2013).

These 2 issues are related and have a common solution. I believe it may aslo solve your problem:

In the registry, the key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet:UseOnlineContent
```

was set to 0 (zero). I changed it to 2 (two) and after restarting my Office 2013 products, the "Sign In" control appeared in the top right hand corner of the ribbon and I was able to access VBA Help by pressing the F1 key.

Comment: This answer is like magic. Over 3 years later, and this fixed my issue from an upgrade to 2016 from 2010.